# How to find row pairs that differ from oneonther substantially in R?

Tags: r

I have a df that shows the percentage of cars that pass through road segments `id`, per hour.
The measurements are further separated into directions `r`.

The last columns are the hour records `1` to `24`.

What I'm interested in is to find the `id`'s where there exists a substantial difference between the hours values, i.e. where the morning/evening traffic differs by direction `r`.

I am lost with how to approach this issue efficiently. It would need to be first a group by `id` and then subtracting the rows from one another and see if any of the values is larger than (e.g.) 2.

The desired output is a vector with the `id` of the ones where the difference is larger than 2 at least for one hour.

The Data:

```
structure(list(id = c("Hochbergerstrasse 55", "Hochbergerstrasse 55", 
"Johanniterbrücke", "Johanniterbrücke", "Wettsteinbrücke", "Wettsteinbrücke", 
"Viaduktstrasse 60 (Rialto)", "Viaduktstrasse 60 (Rialto)", "Dorenbachviadukt", 
"Dorenbachviadukt", "Wasgenring 62", "Wasgenring 62", "Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehen)", 
"Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehen)", "Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)", 
"Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)", "Grenzacherstrasse 511", "Grenzacherstrasse 511", 
"St. Alban-Anlage 72", "St. Alban-Anlage 72"), type = c("13", 
"13", "12", "12", "13", "13", "13", "13", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"13", "13", "12", "12", "14", "14", "13", "13"), source = c("bs", 
"bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", 
"bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs"), r = c("1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2"), `1` = c("0.85003673000000002", "0.84919173299999995", 
"1.5073329710000001", "1.6612883949999999", "1.9605881759999999", 
"1.8001595079999999", "1.8975332069999999", "1.446019935", "1.0564147239999999", 
"0.87236867100000004", "0.93815149399999997", "1.1354737669999999", 
"0.99779897299999998", "1.1513463319999999", "0.72833211899999994", 
"1.089378559", "0.62853551200000002", "0.955223881", "1.446208113", 
"0.99173553699999994"), `2` = c("0.53520831099999999", "0.54225496200000001", 
"1.0456273760000001", "1.087606071", "1.5704711410000001", "1.2988492650000001", 
"1.157495256", "0.92657588099999999", "0.62077978700000003", 
"0.47411340800000001", "0.53277739199999996", "0.67867397500000004", 
"0.58694057200000005", "0.74280408499999995", "0.38844379699999998", 
"0.61896509", "0.251414205", "0.52537313399999996", "0.88183421500000003", 
"0.62442607900000002"), `3` = c("0.461748347", "0.34786167400000001", 
"0.77403584999999997", "0.75295804899999996", "1.1903571070000001", 
"0.86589950999999998", "0.64516129", "0.61771725399999999", "0.37028969699999997", 
"0.331879386", "0.32429928200000002", "0.45679979100000001", 
"0.38151137200000002", "0.46425255300000001", "0.26705510999999998", 
"0.396137658", "0.163419233", "0.29850746299999997", "0.59964726599999996", 
"0.42240587699999999"), `4` = c("0.52471403100000003", "0.40924902800000001", 
"0.62466051099999997", "0.62148918399999997", "1.050315095", 
"0.67221146200000004", "0.49335863400000002", "0.56156114000000001", 
"0.33761707699999999", "0.35084392199999997", "0.31271716500000002", 
"0.45679979100000001", "0.35216434299999999", "0.40854224700000003", 
"0.26705510999999998", "0.29710324300000002", "0.163419233", 
"0.214925373", "0.47619047599999997", "0.36730945799999998"), 
    `5` = c("0.59817399500000001", "0.58317986499999996", "0.59750135800000004", 
    "0.58563403800000002", "0.99029708900000002", "0.64942463299999997", 
    "0.58823529399999996", "0.82830268100000004", "0.37028969699999997", 
    "0.65427650299999995", "0.64859856400000004", "0.77003393399999998", 
    "0.64563462900000002", "0.38997214499999999", "0.50983248400000003", 
    "0.32186184699999998", "0.414833438", "0.26268656699999998", 
    "0.47619047599999997", "0.42240587699999999"), `6` = c("1.122888026", 
    "1.432371598", "1.004888647", "1.0278474959999999", "1.1503451039999999", 
    "0.79753902200000004", "0.85388994299999998", "1.68468342", 
    "0.686125027", "1.7068082689999999", "1.274032893", "1.761942052", 
    "1.555392517", "0.81708449400000005", "1.723719349", "0.74275810799999997", 
    "1.5713387809999999", "0.93134328399999999", "0.74074074099999998", 
    "0.84481175399999997"), `7` = c("3.7464581799999999", "3.5297728670000001", 
    "3.2455187400000001", "2.8445081870000002", "2.8208462540000001", 
    "1.8229463370000001", "2.2580645160000001", "4.0572792360000003", 
    "2.6682639950000002", "5.1204248059999999", "3.1040074130000002", 
    "5.3771861129999996", "4.3286867200000003", "2.2841225629999999", 
    "4.8798252", "1.78261946", "4.9780012569999998", "2.2567164179999999", 
    "1.7989417990000001", "3.2323232320000002"), `8` = c("4.701437716", 
    "4.2766523430000003", "5.4454101030000004", "4.637265448", 
    "5.3315994800000004", "3.6572860889999999", "3.7950664139999999", 
    "5.952548084", "4.5306033540000001", "6.8367153419999998", 
    "5.0961315730000001", "6.3038371179999997", "6.4563462950000003", 
    "3.8068709379999999", "7.7688759410000001", "3.49096311", 
    "8.6989314899999997", "3.4388059700000002", "3.439153439", 
    "8.0808080810000007"), `9` = c("5.4465316399999999", "4.0515653780000003", 
    "5.4861488319999996", "5.3424166370000004", "5.6917075119999998", 
    "4.8763814520000004", "4.5540796959999996", "5.7419626560000001", 
    "4.6286212149999999", "6.4384600799999996", "5.5478341440000003", 
    "5.3249804230000004", "6.4563462950000003", "4.326833798", 
    "6.8220441850000002", "4.4317900469999998", "7.5675675680000003", 
    "4.4417910450000004", "4.2680776009999999", "9.1643709829999995"
    ), `10` = c("5.6774058140000001", "4.2561898920000001", "5.3231939160000001", 
    "5.2946097769999998", "5.3516054820000001", "4.944741939", 
    "4.8007590130000004", "5.7981187700000003", "4.7593116970000002", 
    "5.8410771859999997", "5.2582812140000001", "4.6202036020000001", 
    "5.3705062359999998", "4.8282265549999996", "5.8266569559999999", 
    "5.0507551370000003", "5.9459459460000001", "4.7164179099999997", 
    "4.4444444440000002", "6.299357208"), `11` = c("5.9187742679999999", 
    "5.2383875590000004", "5.6626833239999996", "5.677064659", 
    "5.6216865059999996", "5.5599863279999999", "5.4269449720000003", 
    "5.9946651690000001", "5.4563275969999996", "5.9927934760000001", 
    "5.6057447299999996", "4.9725920129999999", "5.5612619219999999", 
    "5.682451253", "5.8994901679999998", "5.8182718490000003", 
    "6.0339409179999999", "5.3850746269999998", "5.343915344", 
    "5.7667584940000003"), `12` = c("6.391016896", "6.1387354209999998", 
    "5.7577403589999996", "6.2268435520000001", "5.6817045110000004", 
    "6.2435912040000003", "5.8823529409999997", "6.1912115679999999", 
    "6.2622522329999999", "6.2582969850000003", "6.150104239", 
    "5.768728791", "5.9280997800000002", "6.3509749299999996", 
    "6.2151007529999998", "6.6105471649999998", "6.0842237590000003", 
    "6.2328358210000001", "6.4373897710000003", "5.7667584940000003"
    ), `13` = c("6.6533739110000001", "6.2819725799999997", "5.4454101030000004", 
    "5.9400023900000001", "5.1015304590000001", "5.93596901", 
    "5.8064516130000001", "5.5875333429999996", "6.1206708780000003", 
    "5.6229850179999996", "5.8605513089999999", "5.6382145650000002", 
    "5.7079970649999998", "6.5181058500000004", "5.753823744", 
    "6.5362713540000001", "5.6065367689999999", "6.6626865669999997", 
    "6.331569665", "5.1974288340000001"), `14` = c("6.8422709619999997", 
    "6.813996317", "6.3145029880000001", "5.8921955300000004", 
    "6.1118335500000001", "5.9131821809999998", "5.920303605", 
    "6.2473676820000001", "6.2295796120000002", "6.7324103930000003", 
    "6.5323141070000004", "5.8470373269999998", "6.2949376380000004", 
    "6.4252553389999996", "6.3850449139999998", "6.2391681109999997", 
    "6.599622879", "6.1492537309999999", "5.9082892420000004", 
    "6.574839302"), `15` = c("7.3145135899999998", "6.6809903830000001", 
    "6.6539923950000004", "6.5853950040000004", "6.3018905670000001", 
    "6.6309673010000001", "6.451612903", "6.4860311670000002", 
    "6.6325419300000004", "6.6565522469999996", "6.81028492", 
    "5.8992430169999999", "6.7644900950000002", "6.9637883010000001", 
    "6.7006554989999998", "6.981926219", "6.6499057199999996", 
    "6.7104477610000002", "6.4197530860000001", "6.4279155189999999"
    ), `16` = c("7.1361108199999999", "7.4176386330000001", "6.5996740899999997", 
    "6.6451535799999997", "6.33189957", "6.7676882760000003", 
    "6.6034155600000002", "6.4158360239999999", "6.8285776519999999", 
    "6.3910487390000004", "6.7523743339999998", "6.2385800050000002", 
    "6.8378576669999998", "6.9823584030000001", "6.6035445499999996", 
    "6.9076504090000004", "6.7881835319999997", "6.8776119400000004", 
    "6.8077601410000002", "6.1157024790000003"), `17` = c("7.2620421869999996", 
    "8.5635359120000007", "7.1292775669999999", "7.5176287799999999", 
    "6.5019505850000003", "7.4740799820000001", "7.3244781779999997", 
    "6.5843043659999996", "8.1245915919999998", "6.6849990520000002", 
    "8.4433634469999994", "7.0347167839999996", "7.1606749819999997", 
    "7.8737233050000004", "6.8220441850000002", "8.1703391930000002", 
    "7.2030169700000002", "8.3940298510000009", "8.2716049379999994", 
    "6.5197428830000002"), `18` = c("7.3984678349999999", "8.3179864949999995", 
    "7.305812059", "7.4100633440000001", "6.6119835949999999", 
    "8.089324371", "7.9506641370000004", "6.7527727080000002", 
    "8.5928991509999992", "6.6944813200000004", "8.6518415569999991", 
    "7.3610023489999996", "6.6764490099999998", "8.4493964720000001", 
    "6.6763777620000004", "9.2597177520000002", "6.5870521679999996", 
    "9.8029850750000005", "9.9470899470000003", "6.8319559229999998"
    ), `19` = c("6.8002938400000001", "7.0493145080000001", "6.5046170559999998", 
    "6.4658778530000003", "6.2118635590000002", "7.4285063229999997", 
    "7.5332068310000002", "5.9806261410000001", "7.9721193640000001", 
    "6.0496870850000004", "6.9840166779999997", "6.9694596710000001", 
    "6.0308143799999998", "8.0408542250000004", "5.9480456420000003", 
    "8.5169596429999999", "5.7825267130000002", "9.0507462689999993", 
    "8.3421516750000002", "6.2075298439999997"), `20` = c("5.1317032219999996", 
    "5.6374053609999999", "5.1738185769999996", "5.1392374810000003", 
    "5.0715214560000001", "5.411871938", "5.9392789370000001", 
    "4.7592306610000001", "5.8592899149999997", "4.5989000569999998", 
    "4.89923558", "5.4815974939999998", "4.8422597209999996", 
    "5.9424326829999998", "4.5399368779999998", "5.7687546420000002", 
    "4.4626021370000002", "5.755223881", "5.4673721339999997", 
    "4.775022957"), `21` = c("3.431629762", "4.7472887249999998", 
    "3.9244975559999999", "4.003824549", "3.9611883570000002", 
    "4.1358095019999999", "4.3643263760000002", "3.608030324", 
    "4.2147680239999996", "3.252417978", "3.5093815149999998", 
    "3.9937353170000001", "3.6537050619999998", "3.9554317550000002", 
    "3.083272639", "3.6642733349999999", "2.853551226", "3.665671642", 
    "3.8624338620000001", "3.287419651"), `22` = c("2.529121629", 
    "2.895436873", "3.1233025529999998", "3.2389147839999999", 
    "3.3610083020000001", "3.2699099920000001", "3.4535104360000002", 
    "3.0183911270000001", "3.103898933", "2.6645173529999999", 
    "2.6638869590000001", "3.093187157", "2.9933969189999998", 
    "2.9340761369999999", "2.5734401550000001", "2.7234463980000001", 
    "2.1244500309999998", "2.7701492540000001", "3.0511463839999999", 
    "2.387511478"), `23` = c("2.1723160880000001", "2.568037651", 
    "3.0961433999999999", "2.9640253379999999", "3.3410023010000001", 
    "3.1901560899999999", "3.548387097", "2.7095324999999999", 
    "2.7553909820000002", "2.2757443579999999", "2.4785730830000001", 
    "2.8321587049999999", "2.7439471750000002", "2.7112349120000001", 
    "2.2335518329999999", "2.7482050010000001", "1.8101822750000001", 
    "2.7104477610000002", "2.980599647", "2.1671258029999998"
    ), `24` = c("1.3537622", "1.370984244", "2.2542096690000002", 
    "2.4381498750000001", "2.6808042410000001", "2.5635182859999999", 
    "2.7514231499999999", "2.0496981609999998", "1.818775866", 
    "1.498198369", "1.62149641", "1.983816236", "1.672780631", 
    "1.9498607240000001", "1.383831027", "1.8321366670000001", 
    "1.03079824", "1.7910447759999999", "2.2574955910000001", 
    "1.5243342520000001")), row.names = c("X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", 
"X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", 
"X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", "X21"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you looking for the a specific hour of the day? Your question indicates morning/evening, or the difference between all hours of the day? e.g. 1am vs all hours, 2am vs all hours?

Comment: The morning/evening was just an illustrative example, and where the likelihood is the highest. But I'm interested in any hour. The one with the highest difference is what matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is my attempt at a solution. If I understand correctly, you want to find out where the difference between `r = 1` and `r = 2` is the largest for each our of the day? Then I would do something like this (assuming that your data is stored in the `data.frame`/`tibble` `db`:

```
library(tidyverse)
db %>%
  # First let us gather all the hours into a variable and all the percentage pass
  # effectively stacking the data.
  gather(hour, perc_pass, -id, -type, -source, -r) %>%
  # Then, before we pivot the data wider, we just change the values of r to avoid
  # numbers as column names. Possibly easier ways to do this. 
  mutate(
    r = ifelse(r == 1, "dir_1", "dir_2")
  ) %>%
  # Now we can pivot the data wider creating one column with percentage pass for
  # direction 1 and one for direction 2
  pivot_wider(names_from = r, values_from = perc_pass) %>%
  # Simply subtract one column from another to create a variable for the difference
  mutate(
    diff_dir = as.numeric(dir_2) - as.numeric(dir_1)
  ) %>%
  # Filter for values larger than 2, but can be anything, really. 
  filter(abs(diff_dir) > 2)
```

Which then yields a result something like this:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 7
   id                               type  source hour  dir_1             dir_2             diff_dir
   <chr>                            <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>             <chr>                <dbl>
 1 Dorenbachviadukt                 12    bs     7     2.66826399500000~ 5.12042480599999~     2.45
 2 Wasgenring 62                    12    bs     7     3.10400741300000~ 5.37718611299999~     2.27
 3 Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehe~ 13    bs     7     4.32868672000000~ 2.28412256299999~    -2.04
 4 Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)        12    bs     7     4.8798252         1.78261946           -3.10
 5 Grenzacherstrasse 511            14    bs     7     4.97800125699999~ 2.25671641799999~    -2.72
 6 Viaduktstrasse 60 (Rialto)       13    bs     8     3.79506641399999~ 5.952548084           2.16
 7 Dorenbachviadukt                 12    bs     8     4.53060335400000~ 6.83671534199999~     2.31
 8 Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehe~ 13    bs     8     6.45634629500000~ 3.80687093799999~    -2.65
 9 Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)        12    bs     8     7.76887594100000~ 3.49096311           -4.28
10 Grenzacherstrasse 511            14    bs     8     8.69893148999999~ 3.43880597000000~    -5.26
# ... with 12 more rows
```

And we see which streets, types, sources and hours have differences of more than 2 percentage points between directions of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I had missed the other answer... This is basically the same, just with base-R instead of tidyverse functions

Do I understand correctly, that you want the difference between directions per hour? If so, you could do the following. "dat" is the name I gave your data structure.

```
#change traffic values from character to numeric
dat[,5:28] <- apply(dat[,5:28], 2, as.numeric)

#create new data frame with difference values between r = 1 and r = 2 per hour
xdat <- cbind(dat[dat$r == 1, 1:3],
             dat[dat$r == 1, 5:28] - dat[dat$r == 2, 5:28])

#reshape hours to long format
xdat <- reshape(data = xdat, direction = "long", 
                idvar = c("id", "type", "source"), 
                timevar = "hour", varying = 4:27,
                v.names = "trafficDiff", 
                times = colnames(xdat)[4:27])
rownames(xdat) = NULL

#restrict to difference values >= 2
xdat[abs(xdat$trafficDiff) >= 2,]
```

```
                                   id type source hour trafficDiff
65                   Dorenbachviadukt   12     bs    7   -2.452161
66                      Wasgenring 62   12     bs    7   -2.273179
67  Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehen)   13     bs    7    2.044564
68          Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)   12     bs    7    3.097206
69              Grenzacherstrasse 511   14     bs    7    2.721285
74         Viaduktstrasse 60 (Rialto)   13     bs    8   -2.157482
75                   Dorenbachviadukt   12     bs    8   -2.306112
77  Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehen)   13     bs    8    2.649475
78          Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)   12     bs    8    4.277913
79              Grenzacherstrasse 511   14     bs    8    5.260126
80                St. Alban-Anlage 72   13     bs    8   -4.641655
87  Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehen)   13     bs    9    2.129512
88          Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)   12     bs    9    2.390254
89              Grenzacherstrasse 511   14     bs    9    3.125777
90                St. Alban-Anlage 72   13     bs    9   -4.896293
178         Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)   12     bs   18   -2.583340
179             Grenzacherstrasse 511   14     bs   18   -3.215933
180               St. Alban-Anlage 72   13     bs   18    3.115134
187 Äussere Baselstrasse 381 (Riehen)   13     bs   19   -2.010040
188         Bäumlihofstrasse (Riehen)   12     bs   19   -2.568914
189             Grenzacherstrasse 511   14     bs   19   -3.268220
190               St. Alban-Anlage 72   13     bs   19    2.134622
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer as well! It worked great too:)